# 2 dimensional Real space set notation

Tags: notation

Is there such notation as:
$\Bbb R^2_+$

Like $\Bbb R^2$ but with strictly positive numbers?

Or is there better notation for such a set?

Comment: Possibly $ (\Re +)x(\Re +)$

Comment: Some denote it by $\mathbb{H}^n$ ($\mathbb{H}$ for "half space"). I believe $\mathbb{R}^n_+$ is also used.

Comment: Usually it would be denoted $\mathbb{R}_{>0}^{2}$ or $\mathbb{R}_{+}^{2}$ but the latter is somewhat ambiguous as to whether it includes zero or not. It just depends on the context. Different fields and subfields often use vastly different notation.